# access violation ((0xc0000005)) when passing a string to JNI

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I have a simple java class that calls via JNI some native methods implemented in C++.

The java code looks like this

```
String in_test="./xml/input/imagen_0023.xml";
//String in_test="avc";
String out_test=acr.testString2(in_test);
System.out.println("test: " + out_test);
```

The implementation of testString2 is in one dll, called directly by the java program. The definition of the testString2 method is the following.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_accsa_ocr_AutomaticCharacterRecognition_testString2(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring string) 
{
    const char *str = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, 0);

    //std::string s=amt_test_string(str);
    std::string s="hello: "+(std::string)str;
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(string, str);
    return env->NewStringUTF(s.c_str());
}
```

The invoked amt_test_string is defined elsewhere (another dll):

```
std::string AMT_EXPORT amt_test_string(std::string in)
{
    std::string s="path: "+in;
    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
    return s;
}
```

If I run it like this it works neatly, but at soon as I uncomment 
std::string s=amt_test_string(str)
I get an access violation error as follows:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x77ae2cc7, pid=8072, tid=7328
#
# JRE version: 7.0_09-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.5-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x52cc7]  RtlFreeHeap+0xcd
```

But the behaviour is somehow erratic. If I reduce the length of the input argument i.e. using

```
//String in_test="avc";
```

the program works again. From what I've learnt googling, it is something related to using stack allocated variables after they have been released, but I don't really know how to debug this.

EDIT 1: I am compiling this on windows 7 32 bits with Visual Studio 2010 and Oracle's JDK 1.7.09

EDIT 2: The AMT_EXPORT macro is only a convenience shortcut for exporting symbols. See its definition below:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #ifdef AMT_EXPORTS
        #define AMT_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define AMT_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define AMT_EXPORT
#endif
```

Comment: What is `AMT_EXPORT`? It looks like a macro name. You have a problem if it evaluates to `&`.

Comment: Sorry for that I added the definition

Comment: Do both your DLLs link to the same C++ runtime DLL? If not, your C++ there is pretty much guaranteed to crash, with or without Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging JNI code a method posted in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69965/Debugging-a-JNI-Application-using-Netbeans-and-Vis) could be useful (it's about debugging JNI using Netbeans and Visual Studio). It's simple - just start your Java program, then in Visual Studio pick Debug -> Attach to process and choose java.exe process running your program.

When you add breakpoints to your C++ code, Visual Studio will break on them. Voila :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should cast `const char *` to `std::string`

```
std::string s="hello: "+(std::string)str;
```

Replace that by calling the corresponding std::string constructor.

Comment: I agree with you, and I did try that. But that's not the cause of the problem.